# Matlab to rename I file

Tags: string, matlab, printf, rename

I want to save a few images after having processed them. I want the name to be the original name change to look like this. If the original image was named '1', and then I want to rotate the image 90 degrees, I want the new name to be '1_90.png'.

Using this code

```
filename1 = sprintf('%s_%d.png', filename, rotationAngle)

1.png_90.png
```

That is the result. Why would the .png appear before the %d? How can I get the order correctly?

Comment: What is `filename`? Probably `1.png`?

Comment: since you did not post full code you used, one can not see what you did wrong. It works for me. `rotationAngle=90; filename='1'; filename1 = sprintf('%s_%d.png', filename, rotationAngle)` gives `1_90.png`

Comment: Daniel got it right.

How would you remove the .png from the original filename?

Comment: Okay thanks a lot guys. I used

'filename1 = sprintf('%s_%d.png', filename(1), rotationAngle)'

Comment: @user1923086: Please update your question and include [a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), in this case initialisations for your variables.

Answer (score 1):

To get the "name" part of a filename, without the extension, use `fileparts`. This also allows you to reuse the same code for e.g. jpg or other image files, by using a variable for the extension instead of writing '.png'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Daniel and Nasser. I realized how stupid the question is -_-. Still new to this.

```
filename1 = sprintf('%s_%d.png', filename(1), rotationAngle)

1_90.png
```

Comment: That solution only works for filenames with 1 char length, try `12.png`

Comment: only have 10 images. 

For another code I did:

filename1 = sprintf('%s_%d.png', filename(1:end-4), rotationAngle)